# Xiaomi mi scale v1 Weight Data

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, xiaomi, mi

I am trying to writing an application that can take weight measurement from Xiaomi mi scale version 1. I get a hex value like this 0624b2070101002e3800004c04(5.50kg) from the Body Composition Measurement service.

According to my research the first byte gives
02:measurement unit
The last two bytes are the weight value,
But when I convert this value to decimal and divide by 200, I don't get the correct value.

Can someone help me get the correct data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last two bytes are `4c04`. Bluetooth sends data in little endian format so as an integer that is `1100`.

The "GATT Specification Supplement 4" document at https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/ says:

> 3.27.2.7 Weight field
>
> This field is in kilograms with resolution 0.005 if the bit 0 of the Flag field is 0 or in pounds with a resolution of
> 0.01 if the bit 0 of the Flag field is 1.

1100 * 0.005 = 5.5kg

Answer (score 0):

The value of hex `4c04` is equal to 19460 which does not give you the desired result.
But changing the [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (byte-order) to `044c` results in a value of 1100 which, divided by 200, gives you the desired result of 5.5kg

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, here is how i do it personally read the whole thing i had everything documented and don't be intimidated by the looks of it it's pretty simple in fact:

[image]

for the conversion i use this website cause well I don't know how to convert :)
[enter link description here](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/)

here is an image showing  exactly how it works u need to look to the INT 16 BIG endian and post the whole hex code not just the last two bytes like this:
[image]

[image]